# problem in Spring session scope bean with AOP

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I want to inject currentUser instance in HomeController class. so for every request, HomeController will have currentUser object.

My configuration:

```
<bean id="homeController" class="com.xxxxx.actions.HomeController">
    <property name="serviceExecutor" ref="serviceExecutorApi"/>
    <property name="currentUser" ref="currentUser"/>
</bean>

<bean id="userProviderFactoryBean" class="com.xxxxx.UserProvider">
    <property name="userDao" ref="userDao"/>
</bean>

<bean id="currentUser" factory-bean="userProviderFactoryBean" scope="session">
    <aop:scoped-proxy/>
</bean>
```

But I am getting following error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create scoped proxy for bean 'scopedTarget.currentUser': Target type could not be determined at the time of proxy creation.
        at org.springframework.aop.scope.ScopedProxyFactoryBean.setBeanFactory(ScopedProxyFactoryBean.java:94)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1350)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:540)
```

What is the problem? and Is there any better/simple alternative?

Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With scoped-proxies, Spring still needs to know the type of the bean when the context is initialized, and in this case it's failing to do so. You need to try and give it more information.

I notice that you're only specifying `factory-bean` in your definition of `currentUser`, with no `factory-method` specified. I'm actually rather surprised that that's a valid definition, since the two are normally used together. So try adding the `factory-method` attribute to `currentUser`, which specifies the method on `userProviderFactoryBean` which creates the user bean. That method needs to have a return type of your `User` class, which Spring will use to infer the type of `currentUser`.

---

**Edit:** OK, after your comment below, it seems you've misunderstood how to use factory beans in Spring. When you have a bean of type `FactoryBean`, you don't need to use the `factory-bean` attribute as well. So instead of this:

```
<bean id="userProviderFactoryBean" class="com.xxxxx.UserProvider">
    <property name="userDao" ref="userDao"/>
</bean>

<bean id="currentUser" factory-bean="userProviderFactoryBean" scope="session">
    <aop:scoped-proxy/>
</bean>
```

You just need this:

```
<bean id="currentUser" class="com.xxxxx.UserProvider" scope="session">
    <aop:scoped-proxy/>
    <property name="userDao" ref="userDao"/>
</bean>
```

Here, `UserProvider` is a `FactoryBean`, and Spring knows how to handle that. The end result will be that the `currentUser` bean will be whatever `UserProvider` generates, rather than an instance of `UserProvider` itself.

The `factory-bean` attribute is used when the factory is not a `FactoryBean` implementation, but just a POJO, and it allows you to tell Spring explicitly how to use the factory. But because you're using `FactoryBean`, there's no need for this attribute.

Comment: UserProvider class implements FactoryBean interface of Spring. So it already implements methods public Object getObject();  public Class getObjectType(); public boolean isSingleton();. So that's why i have not specified factory-method

Comment: Aah, Silly mistake.. but thanks for making it clear to me. :)